# Loop for particular values of variable in Stata

Tags: loops, foreach, stata

I have a variable `id` and I want a sum of investment for each `id`.

I'm trying to write a loop but it's not correct.

```
 levelsof id2, local(levels)
 foreach l of local levels {
     gen totalgovtake = sum(Real_Gov_Take_MUSD)
 }
```

Comment: As @Cybernike showed you didn't need a loop. Errors in this code included: (1) second time around the loop, it will fail as the new variable already exists (2) nothing in the code implies separate operations for each `id` (3) you are using `sum()` which gives a cumulative or running sum. not a total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to use a loop here. I've created some mock data to illustrate the solution (please try and provide mock data next time you ask a question).

```
input id value
1 20
1 30
1 25
2 60
2 50
3 10
3 20
4 50
end

bysort id: egen total = sum(value)

list, sepby(id)

     +--------------------+
     | id   value   total |
     |--------------------|
  1. |  1      20      75 |
  2. |  1      30      75 |
  3. |  1      25      75 |
     |--------------------|
  4. |  2      60     110 |
  5. |  2      50     110 |
     |--------------------|
  6. |  3      10      30 |
  7. |  3      20      30 |
     |--------------------|
  8. |  4      50      50 |
     +--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helped

Comment: The `egen` function `sum()` still works fine but as from Stata 9 what is documented is the equivalent `egen` function `total()`.